# Sub bottom index text in TextView programmatically

Tags: android, textview

I need to set TextView as "CO2" with 2 as sub-index programmatically.

I can use prepopulated view with string.xml

```
 <string name="co2">CO<sub>2</sub></string> //prints CO2 with sub index
```

But somehow it doesn't work when I set it with code

```
 textView.setText(getString(R.string.co2)); //prints CO2 without sub index
```

I know I can make layout and put 2 textviews, but is this the only way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.co2)));
```

Edit: you'll need to import [android.text.Html](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html).

Comment: thanks for help, but infortunately didn't work. I show dialog with some images and text views, but I guess it doesn't matter

Comment: Ok, seems strange, but if I add some string, like:  "You saved " + getString(R.string.co2), and then Html.fromHtml - then it will return unformatted index. Otherwise it works. But I mark it an answer anyway

Comment: @Roman `+` converts a `CharSequence` to `String`. A String is just a fancy `char[]`, but a `CharSequence` has multiple implementations. One of them is `Spanned` in Android which contains the formatting (spans). If you want to concatenate a `String` and a `CharSequence` containing formatting, use `SpannableStringBuilder` and call `sb.insert(0, "You saved ")`. Make sure you don't call `sb.toString()`, just use `textView.setText(sb)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(Html.fromHtml("Co<sup>2</sup>"));
```

or

http://ftp.gunadarma.ac.id/android/sdk/sdk_310712/docs/resources/faq/commontasks.html#selectingtext (mirror link)